# Why is this linq query creating an inner join rather than a left join

Tags: linq-to-entities

In this linq query I'm expecting it to create a left join on the ApprovedBy column and on the ApprovedByTeUserId column.  When I write out the query it's just ending up a regular inner join for the ApprovedBy field and not even including the TEEmployees table as another left join.

```
var approvedTimesheets = (from t in cdc.ContractJobTimesheetSummaries
join c in cdc.ContractJobs on t.ContractJobId equals c.ContractJobID
join p in cdc.People on c.ContractorID equals p.PeopleID 
join p2 in cdc.People on t.ApprovedBy equals p2.PeopleID into clientApprover 
from ca  in clientApprover.DefaultIfEmpty()
join te in cdc.TEEmployees on t.ApprovedByTeUserId equals te.ID into teApprover 
from te in teApprover.DefaultIfEmpty()

  where jobIds.Contains(t.ContractJobId)
  select new
  {
      t.WeekEnding,
      p.FirstName,
      p.LastName,
      c.PositionTitle,
      t.ApprovedDateTime,
      t.TotalMins,
      t.ContractJobId,
      ClientApprover = ca.FirstName + " " + ca.LastName
  });
```

And the resulting sql query is this.

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[TotalMins] AS [TotalMins], 
[Project1].[WeekEnding] AS [WeekEnding], 
[Project1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Project1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Project1].[PositionTitle] AS [PositionTitle], 
[Project1].[ApprovedDateTime] AS [ApprovedDateTime], 
[Project1].[ContractJobId] AS [ContractJobId], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ContractJobId] AS [ContractJobId], 
    [Extent1].[WeekEnding] AS [WeekEnding], 
    [Extent1].[TotalMins] AS [TotalMins], 
    [Extent1].[ApprovedDateTime] AS [ApprovedDateTime], 
    [Extent2].[PositionTitle] AS [PositionTitle], 
    [Extent3].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent3].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    [Extent4].[FirstName] + N' ' + [Extent4].[LastName] AS [C1]
    FROM    [dbo].[ContractJobTimesheetSummary] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ContractJob] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ContractJobId] = [Extent2].[ContractJobID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[People] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ContractorID] = [Extent3].[PeopleID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[People] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[ApprovedBy] = [Extent4].[PeopleID]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ContractJobId] IN (cast(16243 as decimal(18)), cast(16472 as decimal(18)))
)  AS [Project1]
```

In another class I have a nearly identical query with a different starting table and it works fine.  I have no idea why one acts differently than the other.  Any ideas what's wrong?  Here's the query that generates the two left joins.

```
var approvedExpenses = (from t in cdc.ContractJobTimesheetExpenses
join c in cdc.ContractJobs on t.ContractJobId equals c.ContractJobID
join p in cdc.People on c.ContractorID equals p.PeopleID 
join r in cdc.Reimbursements on t.ReimbursementId equals r.ReimbursementId
join p2 in cdc.People on t.ApprovedBy equals p2.PeopleID into clientApprover 
from ca  in clientApprover.DefaultIfEmpty()
join te in cdc.TEEmployees on t.ApprovedByTeUserId equals te.ID into teApprover 
from te in teApprover.DefaultIfEmpty()

where t.ApprovedDateTime.HasValue && jobIds.Contains(t.ContractJobId) select new {
    p.FirstName,
    p.LastName,
    t.ApprovedDateTime,
    t.ExpenseAmount,
    t.ExpenseDate,
    r.PublicName,
    t.ContractJobId,
    t.UniqueId,
    ClientApprover = ca.FirstName + " " + ca.LastName,
    t.ApprovedBy, t.ApprovedByTeUserId
});
```

Comment: Appears to be a bug in EF - which EF version are you using?

Comment: We're using 6.1.3